# React Native handle socket connection's events when app is in background?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, websocket, react-native-push-notification

I'm working on Chat app using React native and `WebSocket` everything works fine in active mode but when you push the home button to make the app in background mode, the `WebSocket` onMessage events function is not triggered

The good thing is that `WebSocket` connection is still connected but the events function not triggered.

I just want to push the notification when receiving a message in the background mode.

I did a research and I found that I need to run a silent background audio track at all times(some said this illegal way).

Is there a legal API to keep a connection alive in the background?

Do I need to re-connect the socket connection in the background mode

My code

```
events = (data) =>{

    if(data[0].message){
          if(this.state.appState !== 'active'){
             console.log('check here') // not working when the app in background mode
              PushNotification.localNotification({// not working when the app in background mode
                    message: data[0].message, 
                    number: 1,
                    title: 'a new message from: '+data[0].username,

                });
            }else{
                this.setState({messages: data[0]})
            }
    }
}


socketConnect = () =>{
        AsyncStorage.getItem('token').then((token) => {
        let connection = new wamp.Connection({ url: 'wss://*******/',
            realm: 'realm',
            authmethods: ['jwt'],
        });
        connection.onopen = (session, detalis) => {

            session.subscribe('messages', this.events);
        };
        connection.open();

        })
    };
```

Comment: I have done the same, write my own code in android/ios to handle and expose that to react native.

Comment: Well, so currently there's no way to do that with react native or install packages?

Comment: @BiplabDe Can you share your code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I did a research and I found that I need to run a silent background
>   audio track at all times(some said this illegal way).

Yes, that would definitely result in a rejection by the Apple/Google app review team.

> Is there a legal API to keep a connection alive in the background?

Actually you don't need that (see solution below)

### Solution:

I assume you have a server, where you manage all the websocket connections and route the message to the expected client. You can use [firebase cloud messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging) to send the user an ios/android push notification, which informs him/her that there is  a new message. Of course you need FCM on both your server and app side. For the app part you could use for example [react-native-firebase](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase). For the server there are several [libraries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/libraries) available. Now there are two cases:

**case 1)**

If the app is already in the foreground, you can either show a  LocalNotification via FCM(react-native-firebase) or you just use your websocket connection to display the message.

**case 2)**

Your app is in background, again you send a push notification via FCM from your server. The big advantage is that FCM communicates with the Apple Push Notification Service and the Google Cloud Messaging Service (btw google will soon just use FCM). That means your user gets a native push notification with a preview text or a full message (that's up to you). Then the user clicks on the notification and your app opens again. At this point you can reconnect to your websocket and then you can continue with your normal app behavior.

Additional remarks:

1. This is probably the only legal way
2. It's much more energy efficient to use APNS/GMS/FCM than keeping the app always in background

Comment: Thank you for your answer, your solution is working but I don't want to use a remote push notification solution, I've added my code will help you to understand what I want to achieve,

Comment: @Liam you're welcome. Unfortunately, I think a remote push notification is the only way to achieve your desired behavior. A LocalNotification never fires in background. Another advantage of remote push notifications is, when your app gets killed by the user, the user will still receive a message, which would be impossible with your implemented approach.

Comment: Thank you, your answer really helpful. My backend is PHP do you suggest a package to work with react native firebase?

Comment: @Liam you're welcome. Actually I already did this with php, but I have to check which library I used. I will get back to you, as soon as I have time to check the lib. And thanks for rewarding me the bounty.

Comment: What we need to do for react native windows app?