# how to send push notifications from node.js server to a react native app even when the app is closed without using APNS/GCM/FCM/SNS...?

Tags: react-native, socket.io, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-push-notification, react-native-background-fetch

I did some research and I found these tools [coggle](https://coggle.it/diagram/YZYqAOlLLgWOZ-PJ/t/-), I don't know if it is possible to do this and if it is, how to do the background tasks in a way that I can receive notifications even when the app is closed, how to handle socket connection when the app is closed ?

I already seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55900662/react-native-handle-socket-connections-events-when-app-is-in-background) question and I am asking if there is a solution now.

Comment: use onesignal,framework that works both for ios/android  and it free,you can use there api

Comment: thanks for the comment but I want to know if it is possible to do without 3rd party services onesignal has its own pricing it is not totally free

Comment: to be honest i use it,it is free if you don't need to alot of customizations,it is really hard without onesignal you will need to impelement the following , push notification server for ios and you will 100% write native code,it is not very complex most of the work will be done in appdelegate in ios (objective-c) then you will need to impelement a bridage from objective c to react native javascript /for android you will need to create a custom activity for that and do the same,if you are not very experienced in writing native i don't recommend that

Comment: about handling socket connection when app is closed,well there is nothing to do,unless you write native,you need to reconnect when is app is opened

Comment: Sorry for late answer. I was thinking of an easier solution of using react-native-background-actions or react-native-background-tasks to request notifications list from server every 15min and when the app is open I'll use socket communication for real-time notifications. Thank you for the valuable answer.